# Adding custom path by updating ~/.profile with not working

Tags: environment-variables, user-profile

I have altered my ~/.profile file by adding the following:

```
PATH="/user/share/android-sdk-linux/tools:$PATH"
```

I then log off and log in again, but the path is not added to the $PATH environment variable.  I am checking in terminal:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/share/android-sdk-linux/tools:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_17/bin
```

Please advise

**Edit**

I have even tried:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/android-sdk-linux/tools
EXPORT PATH
```

No luck here either.

**Edit 2**

~/.profile:

```
 # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set path to android
# PATH = $PATH:/usr/share/android-sdk-linux/tools
# EXPORT PATH

PATH="/usr/share/android-sdk-linux/tools:$PATH"
```

Adding to ~/.bachrc or /etc/environment:

```
PATH="/usr/share/android-sdk-linux/tools:$PATH"
```

works, but why not ~/.profile?

Comment: As a note, in 13.04 and later you can install `android-tools-adb` and `android-tools-fastboot` directly from Software Center to get adb and fastboot. It doesn't exactly answer your question, but since I recognized what you were doing I figured I'd leave a comment.

Comment: If you want PATH for all users: read my answer.

Comment: @PeppeDAlterio I want to add a custom path, not interdict.

Comment: Do you mean a different PATH for each user?

Comment: Right now I just want it to work for me.

Comment: @AndroidAddict I edited your question because I based my answer on your original question. From your **Edit 2** someone can understand that you you turned that thing. Also, and I edited my answer after your edits.

Comment: adding an "export PATH" at the end of `.profile` should work as well

Comment: There is lies the problem.  You can see from my post that I do add it to the end of the ~/.profile file and log-off/on and still no path update.  It however does work by adding it to ~/.bashrc.  That's why I am confused - it should be working because there is neither ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to permanently change the value of the PATH envar.
In Ubuntu the PATH envar is defined inside the `/etc/environment` file. So you need to modify the PATH envar declaration inside that file, not inside the .profile!
**Use this only if you want to change the PATH value for every users!**

Comment: This is totally not indicated. What if there are more than one user on the system?

Comment: Yep, you're right...I'm adding a "warning" to my answer. Thank you

Comment: I do.  That's intentional.

Answer (score 19):

Don't use a space before or after `=` when you assign a value to a variable in bash. The right way is:

```
PATH="/user/share/android-sdk-linux/tools:$PATH"
```

For the changes to take effect, restart your computer or source your `.profile` file using the following command:

```
source ~/.profile
```

If you want to change the path for all users, add that line in `/etc/profile` file. Again a restart is required.

Comment: Removed spaces and quoted path verbatim as you have here and still does not so in echo.

Comment: Can you pastebin the output of `cat ~/.profile` and `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @AndroidAddict You need a restart or source your `~/.profile` in terminal until restart: `source ~/.profile`

Comment: Do not need to restart. It is enough to log in again.